# Read raw MPMediaItem data from iCloud item

Tags: ios, icloud, pcm

I have written an iOS app that allows you to play back music on your iPhone/iPad at slower/faster speeds but at the origin an pitch (for practicing playing music, dancing, etc).

The app reads raw PCM data from the songs stored on the device no problem, using `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`. But, this fails when trying to load raw PCM data from songs stored in iCloud. Does anyone know if this is possible? As far as I know, Apple have not published an API for doing this, and the APIs used for reading raw PCM from songs stored on the device do not work with iCloud items.

Some of my users have requested playback of songs stored in iTunes, so any help would be greatly appreciated.